# Why did my Kinect framerate slow down?

Tags: usb-3, kinect

I've used Kinect Studio with high framerate lately it's quite choppy. I tried the same camera on another computer and it ran as expected.

- Using powered adapter
- Using USB 3.0
- Using Windows 10

I've tried unplugging other usb devices with no luck. How can I troubleshoot this further? Could it be related to recently installed software?

Comment: Have you tried closing all other running applications?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Yes. I went a step further and disabled a few startup programs and rebooted. I'm starting to think a reformat may be necessary..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone added a USB extension to the end of the Kinect. It was a USB 3.0 extension from "Amazon Basics". I bypassed the extension and everything worked as expected.

I'm surprised as the extension works fine with the Oculus but not the Kinect. I guess the Kinect must max out the amount of info a USB 3 cable can throughput.